# How can i add devexpress vertical Panes chart in my project?

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I'm beginner in asp.net and i want use devexpress web chart control in my project,in this link:

[THIS](https://demos.devexpress.com/XtraChartsDemos/ChartElements/VerticalPanes.aspx)

but up link dont write any code or tutorial to how to use that chart in project,how can I write simple code to use up chart in my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a ChartControl to your ASP.NET project as any other controls. Just add a WebForm to your project and drag-drop a WebChartControl from Toolbox onto the WebForm. To add panes to a chart, add several panes to your Diagram:

```
<dxcharts:XYDiagram>
...
     <Panes>
                    <dxcharts:XYDiagramPane PaneID="0" Name="Pane 1"></dxcharts:XYDiagramPane>
                    <dxcharts:XYDiagramPane PaneID="1" Weight="1.5" Name="Pane 2"></dxcharts:XYDiagramPane>
                </Panes>
</dxcharts:XYDiagram>
```

See the [Adding Panes](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument5880) help topic.

In addition, check out the [ASPChartsChartElementsVerticalPanes](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VYD-lLv4TY0) video that illustrates how to create a chart with several panes from scratch.